# Removing console.log from React Native app

Tags: performance, automation, react-native, console.log

Should you remove the `console.log()` calls before deploying a React Native app to the stores? Are there some performance or other issues that exist if the `console.log()` calls are kept in the code?

Is there a way to remove the logs with some task runner (in a similar fashion to web-related task runners like Grunt or Gulp)? We still want them during our development/debugging/testing phase but not on production.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

believe best practice is to wrap your debug code in statements such as...

```js
    if(__DEV__){
        console.log();
    }
```

This way, it only runs when you're running within the packager or emulator. More info here...
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#using-consolelog-statements

This would also work...

```js
__DEV__ && console.log('logged only in __DEV__');
```

Answer (score 79):

Well, you can always do something like:

```
if (!__DEV__) {
  console.log = () => {};
}
```

So every `console.log` would be invalidated as soon as `__DEV__` is not true.

Comment: This is cleaner, and should be the accepted answer. Just make sure these lines run before everything else.

Comment: @csotiriou: so would that mean at the top of App.js before all imports?

Comment: @raarts yes. However I have the feeling that react native is doing this automatically, but only for the default release builds. In Xcode, even if I add a custom release build, it doesn't hide the logs. Still trying to find an alternative though.

Comment: Does this also work in React JS? Is the `__DEV__` constant documented somewhere?

Comment: You can provide an environment variable to define whether the app in development or production and do the same as the answer indicates. If you use webpack I believe you can use `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Comment: I like this answer. It's really clean, however facebook's docs suggest using babel-plugin-transform-remove-console as pointed out by @adam. Has anyone tried this ? and does it really work ? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-consolelog-statements

Comment: This answer is two years-old, it was correct for the time of writing as well for nowadays, @adambene's reply does not make this incorrect.

Comment: If you go for this solution, i think console.warn, console.error and etc need to be included as well. I was also thinking the use of Babel transpiler is actually more optimized than the invalidation process at run time?

Comment: @kodeCoala yes I have used it in my code base, it's easy to use and gets the job done well!

Answer (score 71):

Babel transpiler can remove `console` statements for you with the following plugin:

```
npm i babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save-dev
```

Edit .babelrc:

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```

And `console` statements are stripped out of your code.

source: https://hashnode.com/post/remove-consolelog-statements-in-production-in-react-react-native-apps-cj2rx8yj7003s2253er5a9ovw

Comment: Better to use -D rather than --save to save it to devDependencies.

Comment: I tried this but couldnt find .babelrc file in my directory

Comment: @JayakrishnanMenon then obviously you have to create .babelrc, and setup babel transpiler

Comment: I am kind of a noob in this. Can you explain a bit more on that?

Comment: Going through same situation. Can you explain in detail?

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov Can you explain that a bit further? Shouldn't it only remove them console.log statements in production? Doesn't -D (devDependencies) mean that you are run in development mode and not production mode. Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @kojow7 babel plug-ins should be used only on dev machine and not included into apps bundle.

Comment: before adding above code my .babelrc having "presets": ["react-native"], should I keep including the line? at android build i am getting this warning message "You or one of the Babel plugins you are using are using Flow declarations as bindings.
Support for this will be removed in version 7. To find out the caller, grep for this message and change it to a `console.trace()`"

Comment: How do these environments work? How does react-native know it is a production build? Is there a staging and production environment as well?

Comment: is this work when we create build using Xcode or android studio

Comment: Do we need this with the current React Native process ? Since React Native automatically use babel to minify our code, do we still need to add this babel config ?
And also by doind this, does it removed the default minifying of React Native ?

Answer (score 17):

I know this question has already been answered, but just wanted to add my own two-bits. Returning `null` instead of `{}` is *marginally* faster since we don't need to create and allocate an empty object in memory.

```
if (!__DEV__)
{
   console.log = () => null
}
```

This is obviously **extremely** minimal but you can see the results below

```js
// return empty object
console.log = () => {}
console.time()
for (var i=0; i<1000000; i++) console.log()
console.timeEnd()

// returning null
console.log = () => null
console.time()
for (var i=0; i<1000000; i++) console.log()
console.timeEnd()
```

Although it is more pronounced when tested elsewhere:

[image: empty console function]

Honestly, in the real world this probably will have no significant benefit just thought I would share.

Comment: The {} in () => {} is an empty function body, not an object. Returning a object would be () => ({}). Also, if you switch the order of the performance tests to see, the first one will show as taking longer.

Answer (score 8):

I tried it using `babel-plugin-transform-remove-console` but the above solutions didn't work for me .

If someone's also trying to do it using `babel-plugin-transform-remove-console` can use this one.

`npm i babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save-dev`

Edit `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = (api) => {
  const babelEnv = api.env();
  const plugins = [];
  if (babelEnv !== 'development') {
    plugins.push(['transform-remove-console']);
  }
  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found the following to be a good option as there is no need to log even if __DEV__ === true, if you are not also remote debugging.

In fact I have found certain versions of RN/JavaScriptCore/etc to come to a near halt when logging (even just strings) which is not the case with Chrome's V8 engine.

```
// only true if remote debugging
const debuggingIsEnabled = (typeof atob !== 'undefined');

if (!debuggingIsEnabled) {
    console.log = () => {};
}
```

[Check if in remote JS debugging is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022216/react-native-programmatically-check-if-in-remote-js-debugging-is-enabled)

Answer (score 1):

Using `Sentry` for tracking exceptions automatically disables `console.log` in production, but also uses it for tracking logs from device. So you can see latest logs in sentry exception details (breadcrumbs).

Comment: Hi, can you link to a document of sentry that show how to disable console.log? Or do they do that automatically without the need of any config? (I can't seem to find info about this)

Comment: @friedegg-bacon-sandwich they do that automatically.

Comment: Great! :) But do you have a link to some docs to confirm this? I can't seem to find it anywhere

Comment: @TamRock docs are quite bad :) but i found this https://blog.sentry.io/2017/01/19/node-breadcrumbs#getting-started for nodejs. I guess they copied this behavior to RN.

Comment: Looking at Sentry's code, I don't think that `console.log()` statements are removed. Here's what I'm referencing: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/blob/master/packages/integrations/src/captureconsole.ts

Answer (score -1):

**This works:**

Go to index.html file and at the end add this 1 liner:

```
<script>console.log=function(){};</script>
```

Or, go to index.js file and at the end add this 1 liner:

```
console.log=function(){};
```

Done