# React native - Programmatically check if in remote JS debugging is enabled

Tags: react-native

On React-Native, how can I know if `"Debug JS Remotely"` is enabled?

I tried looking in [RN docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html) and various NPM packages, but couldn't find out how...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How to programmatically check if remote debugging is enabled (just found this peculiar behaviour today on another SO question). Tested on RN 0.43 and with Chrome debugger + React Native Debugger :

```
const isDebuggingEnabled = (typeof atob !== 'undefined');
```

**Edit:** just noticed this was asked over half a year ago :D... well, I leave it here for future generations.

Comment: If you are using react-native-web `isDebuggingEnabled` will always be true 

Answer (score 10):

A class `DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope` exists iff remote debugging is enabled (it is the constructor of global object in that case). Thus we can:

```
const haveRemoteDev = (typeof DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope) !== 'undefined';
```

Answer (score 8):

You can check `global.nativeCallSyncHook`

```
if (!global.nativeCallSyncHook) {
  console.log("Debug JS Remotely")
}
```

see more at: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/417e191a1cfd6a049d1d4b0a511f87aa7f176082

Answer (score 6):

Ran across this answer, but wasn't happy with checking for `atob` or being constrained to android. I found a function that appears to be a pretty good proxy for if the debugger is running, which is a global called `__REMOTEDEV__`.

In my case, I wanted to see requests made by the app in react-native-debugger, my full code is as follows:

```
/**
 * When the debugger is connected, remove the XHR polyfill
 * so that the chrome inspector will be able to see requests
 */
if (typeof global.__REMOTEDEV__ !== 'undefined') {
  const _XHR = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest ?
      GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest :
      GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;

  global.XMLHttpRequest = _XHR;
}
```

Comment: `global.__REMOTEDEV__` is `undefined` even in debug mode.

Comment: not working in RN 0.55 / Chrome 66 :( not sure when they changed it

Answer (score 6):

Check `__REMOTEDEV__` in a simple way:

```
if(global.__REMOTEDEV__) { console.log('Remote Debug'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, any of the following answers didn't work for me...

I found out that the location pathname changes to `/debugger-ui` on global object:

```js
if (global.location && global.location.pathname.includes('/debugger-ui')) {
  Alert.alert('Remote debug is on');
} else {
  Alert.alert('Remote debug is off');
}
```

Working on RN 0.59.

Comment: Not sure why other answers have many upvotes and your has 0, it is indeed the only one working for me on RN 0.63

Answer (score 0):

For Android, in the a shared preferences you can find the remote debug status.
When I open the sharedPreferences file for my app.

Remote debug active

```
<map>
    <boolean name="remote_js_debug" value="true" />
    <boolean name="hot_module_replacement" value="true" />
    <boolean name="reload_on_js_change" value="true" />
</map>
```

Remote debug inactive

```
<map>
    <boolean name="remote_js_debug" value="false" />
    <boolean name="hot_module_replacement" value="true" />
    <boolean name="reload_on_js_change" value="true" />
</map>
```

So (Android only), you can use a module like this one : https://github.com/sriraman/react-native-shared-preferences to check if the remote debug is active.