# React native hide/open all console log

Tags: react-native, console.log

Hi everyone I searched and learned `console.logs` hurts performance.So I choose to disable logs when creating apk.I find away but doesn't worked for me. They all say add this lines to `.babelrc` file but I don't have any. so I created `.babelrc` and added this lines but console logs still appering in browser.
lines.

I installed this package

```
npm i babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save-dev
```

So what should I change

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
```

}

project structure

[image: structure]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing console.log from React Native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939917/removing-console-log-from-react-native-app)

Comment: Where should I put this code if (!__DEV__) {
  console.log = () => {};
}

Comment: Probably in the entry point of the app

Comment: I got a lot of pages. How can I put this into App.js

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution to remove all logs from any where:

```
if (!__DEV__) {
  for (const iterator of Object.keys(global.console)) {
    global.console[iterator] = () => null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At very beginning in App.js
Paste this code

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;

if (!__DEV__) {
    console.log = () => {};
    console.warn = () => {};
    console.error = () => {};
}
```

Comment: I want to add `Platform.OS` for console.log because I am running both IOS + Android simulator, so I want to detect where log from, can u help?

Answer (score 0):

It should be added to `babel.config.js` instead.

The default `babel.config.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

You can adapt it further

```
module.exports = api => {
  const isProd = api.env('production');

  const plugins = isProd ? ["transform-remove-console"] : []

  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins,
  }
}
```

When building a production build with the following command, open `android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle` to see whether there are any console statements.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

This will only remove console statements from your code, any console statements within libraries within `node_modules` will still be present.